# on x axis just want few values (1 and 4) rather than 1 to 5 and want same graph lines results using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I want to draw the graph using matplotlib but just want values as i mention in graph 1 and 5 but the results should be the same. this is the graph which i want but when i choose just 1 and 5 graphs shape is changed, i have posted the code blew, thanks in advance.
[Required graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut3T3.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
if __name__ == '__main__':


    TM = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']

    a =[4.1, 5.1, 6.0, 7.0, 8.1, 9.1]

    b =[6.1, 7.2, 8.1, 9.1, 10.1, 11.0]

    c =[7.2, 8.5, 9.3, 10.2, 11.2, 12.0]


  
    figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 11))

    A, =plt.plot(TM, a, marker='*',markersize=30, c='g', lw=4, ls='-', label='AA')  
    B, =plt.plot(TM, b, marker='o',markersize=30, c='b', lw=4, ls='-', label='BB') 
    C, =plt.plot(TM, c, marker='d',markersize=30, c='r', lw=4, ls='-', label='CC')


    font1 = {'family': 'Times New Roman',
              'weight': 'normal',
              'size': 40,
              }
    legend = plt.legend(handles=[A, B, C], prop=font1, ncol=3, labelspacing=0.02, handlelength=1, handleheight=1,
                        handletextpad=0.5, columnspacing=0.5, borderaxespad=0.1, borderpad=0.2)
    legend._legend_box.align = "right"

 
    plt.tick_params(labelsize=50)
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()
    [label.set_fontname('Times New Roman') for label in labels]
   
    font2 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
    'weight' : 'normal',
    'size'   :50,
    }
    
    plt.ylim((0, 20)) 
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 20, 3))
    plt.xlabel('Time', font2)
    plt.ylabel('Sec', font2)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoEop.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the output graph with this exact code? Because, I am getting a `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (6,)`. Not sure why you have passed TM as the first argument. I am assuming `TM = np.arange(6)` to get the second graph.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake while posting, check it now please

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but `TM = [0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5]` would give you your required graph.

Comment: your idea won't work because it's same like TM = ['0','1','2','3','4','5'], i just want two values on x-axis rest of everything same.

Comment: Then you can just supply the first and last values for each of `a`, `b`, and ,`c`, and then have TM as `[0, 5]`.

Comment: can you please edit that in code and post? i didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If would only like to plot the first and last elements of a list, then just supply those two elements for each array.

If you would like to keep the original list intact, then a function that would filter only the first and last elements can be used like below.

```
def fl(array): #first and last
    return [array[0], array[-1]]

figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 11))

A, =plt.plot(fl(TM), fl(a), marker='*',markersize=30, c='g', lw=4, ls='-', label='AA')  
B, =plt.plot(fl(TM), fl(b), marker='o',markersize=30, c='b', lw=4, ls='-', label='BB') 
C, =plt.plot(fl(TM), fl(c), marker='d',markersize=30, c='r', lw=4, ls='-', label='CC')
```

[image]

If what you want is to remove the intermediate numbers from the x-axis ticks, then just use this command before displaying the graph

```
plt.xticks([0,5])
```

[image]

Comment: I want the same results but in a different way. Plotted values should be displayed same as original graph but time values shout be (0-5) and skip (1-4). Values of (1-4) should be plotted same as original graph

Comment: Edited the answer to update x axis ticks. Does that solve your problem?